# Monitor battery level from Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I am trying to monitor the current battery status using a `Service`. I wrote some code and I can show the battery level using the log once but I want to monitor the battery level according to a timer every 5 seconds.

```
public class ServiceStatusUpdate extends Service {
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        while (true) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    batteryLevel();
                    Log.e("Status changed", "Status changed");
                }
            }, 5000);
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    }

    private void batteryLevel() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                Log.e("Batarry status iss", level + "mm");
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
        return;
    }
}
```

**`MainActivity.java`:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this, ServiceStatusUpdate.class));
    }
}
```

**`manifest.xml` source:**

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".OnBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".ServiceStatusUpdate"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

**`OnBootReceiver`:**

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //int batteryLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, ServiceStatusUpdate.class);

            context.startService(serviceLauncher);
        }
    }
}
```

I am also trying to send an HTTP request every /xxx times. The HTTP request will include some text, the battery status, and latitude and longitude.

I know how to send the request with parameters, but my service is working only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unregistering the `batteryLevelReceiver` after the first time it receives a broadcast. Remove this line from `onReceive` to continue to receive broadcasts:

```
context.unregisterReceiver(this);
```

Also, you probably only want to register and unregister your broadcast receiver once when the server is created/destroyed so you should register in `onCreate` and unregister in `onDestroy`.

Here is some code that should be very close to what you want. Note that all of this will run on the UI thread currently.

```
public class ServiceStatusUpdate extends Service {

    private static final int CHECK_BATTERY_INTERVAL = 5000;

    private GPSTracker gps;
    private double batteryLevel;
    private Handler handler;

    private BroadcastReceiver batInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent batteryIntent) {
            int rawlevel = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

            if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                batteryLevel = (rawlevel * 100.0) / scale;
            }

            Log.e("Battery status is", batteryLevel + "mm");
        }
    };

    private Runnable checkBatteryStatusRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH LATEST BATTERY LEVEL STORED IN batteryLevel HERE...

            // schedule next battery check
            handler.postDelayed(checkBatteryStatusRunnable, CHECK_BATTERY_INTERVAL);
            Log.e("Battery status is", batteryLevel + "mm cached");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(checkBatteryStatusRunnable, CHECK_BATTERY_INTERVAL);
        registerReceiver(batInfoReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(batInfoReceiver);
        handler.removeCallbacks(checkBatteryStatusRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: i updated my MainActivity.java source. ps i removed batteryLevel method and Log.e Status changed messige showing only once

Comment: i want to check every XXX time battary status by service

Comment: Well that is different from what you asked originally. Give me a minute and I'll update the answer.

Comment: did you test it? i use genymotion and Log message showing only onnce

Comment: It's working just fine. The broadcast receiver is only called when the battery level changes. That is why there is a handler with a scheduled runnable where you can process the latest value every 5 seconds. I added a log statement to the runnable so you can try again and see for yourself.